# Split multiple values from LookupSet in multiple columns in Report Builder

Tags: sql, report, reportbuilder

I am struggeling with an expression in the report builder.
My dataset can contain multiple values. So I used LookupSet and joined the result.
This works so far.

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!r_configuration.Value, "RData"), ",")
```

Result

```
|Column 1 | Column 2|
----------|----------
|   1,2   |         |
|   1     |         |
```

Now I want to split the result. For example, if there are multiple values the first entry should be in column1 and the second in column2

```
|Column 1 | Column 2|
----------|----------
|   1     |    2    |
|   1     |         |
```

I tried with

```
=LookupSet(Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!r_configuration.Value, "RData")(0)
```

But this only works if the lookupset contains multiple values. if there is just one value I receive #Error.
It tried to put an IIF(), isNothing() but still get the #Error.
Any ideas how to achive this?

The following doesn't work neighter

```
=IIF(LookupSet(Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!r_configuration.Value, "RDataset").Length > 1,LookupSet(Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!r_configuration.Value, "RDataset")(0),Join(LookupSet(Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!r_configuration.Value, "RDataset"),","))
```

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nothing works with the build in expressions.
I added custom code. This works always :-)

```
Public Function GetRitop(ByVal items as Object(), ByVal pos as Integer) As Object

if items Is Nothing Then
return ""
Else if items.Length = 1 And pos = 1 Then
return items(0)
Else if items.Length = 1 And pos = 2 Then
return ""
Else if items.Length = 2 And pos = 1 Then
return items(0)
else if items.Length = 2 And pos = 2
return items(1)
End if

End Function
```

The expression in the cell is

```
=Code.GetRitop(LookupSet(Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!SignalId.Value, Fields!r_configuration.Value, "RDataset"),1)
```

where 1 is the array position